# Mongoose findAndModify remove?

Tags: mongoose

Is there a findAndModify method on the Model where I can pass in the remove option? I need to get the `_id`s of documents that are removed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Model.findOneAndRemove`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndRemove) for that.

Comment: But I need to find all documents that match the conditions passed.

Comment: @paulkon There isn't a multi-doc version (the `findAndModify` command you mention only applies to a single doc as well).  So you can either do one at a time using `findOneAndRemove` or `find` all the matching docs and then `remove` them.